How do I test my guards in Nestjs to throw an exception?
I am trying to my authentication guard in nestJS. I want to test it to return an exception but the test keeps failing. In fact I need help on how to test authentication guards.
this is my authentication guard
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../auth.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export interface decodedObj {
    sub: string
    email: string
    iat: number
    exp: number
 
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
      const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      let token = ''

      if ( request.headers.authorization &&
        request.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")){
           token = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else {
          throw new UnauthorizedException('Please login!')
        }
      
      if (!token) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Please login!');
      }

      // verify the token
      const decoded: decodedObj = this.jwtService.verify(token, {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      });

      
      // check if the user exists
      const user = await this.userModel.findById(decoded.sub);

      if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('User does not exist');
      }

      // check if user changed password after token was issued
      if (user.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException(
         `User recently changed password. Please log in again!`,
      );  
      }

      request.user = user;
  
    return true;
  }
}

this is my authentication.guard.spec.ts file
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './authentication.guard';
import { User } from '../auth.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ExecutionContext, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/nestjs-testing';

describe('AuthenticationGuard', () => {
  let guard: AuthenticationGuard;
  let jwtService: JwtService;
  let model: Model<User>;

  const mockModelUser = {
    findById: jest.fn(),
  };

  const jwtMock = {
    verify: jest.fn(),
  };

  const mockUser = {
    _id: '61c0ccf11d7bf83d153d7c06',
    name: 'kingsley',
    email: 'kingsleyokgeorge@gmail.com',
    password: 'helloooo',
    passwordConfirm: 'helloooo',
    role: 'user',
    active: true,
  };

  const mockExecutionContext = {
    switchToHttp: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      getRequest: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValue({ headers: {} }),
    }),
  };


  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthenticationGuard,
        UnauthorizedException,
        {
          provide: JwtService,
          useValue: jwtMock,
        },
        {
          provide: getModelToken(User.name),
          useValue: mockModelUser,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    model = module.get<Model<User>>(getModelToken(User.name));
    jwtService = module.get<JwtService>(JwtService);
    guard = module.get<AuthenticationGuard>(AuthenticationGuard);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('can activate', () => {
    it('should return an exception if authorization not exist ', async () => {
      
      const guardMock = await guard.canActivate(
        mockExecutionContext as unknown as ExecutionContext,
      );

      expect(guardMock).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException)
    });
  });
});


this is what my failing test keeps showing an i don't understand it:
 FAIL  src/auth/authentication/authentication.guard.spec.ts (13.266 s)
  AuthenticationGuard
    √ should be defined (28 ms)
    can activate
      × should return an exception if authorization not exist  (4 ms)

  ● AuthenticationGuard › can activate › should return an exception if authorization not exist

    UnauthorizedException: Please login!

      35 |            token = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      36 |         } else {
    > 37 |           throw new UnauthorizedException('Please login!')
         |                 ^
      38 |         }
      39 |
      40 |       if (!token) {

      at AuthenticationGuard.canActivate (auth/authentication/authentication.guard.ts:37:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (auth/authentication/authentication.guard.spec.ts:70:37)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.293 s
Ran all test suites matching /authentication.guard.spec.ts/i.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.

Please help!!!

Remove await from const guardMock = await guard.canActivate(... and add await for expect(guardMock).rejects... => await expect(guardMock).rejects

Thank you so much! it worked! but can you explain why?

As mentioned by @hoangdv, executing code that throws will eventually just rethrow that error in the test case.
If you want to test for throwing errors, you have to do this within the expect statement. This does apply for async and sync errors:
Async
When testing async throws (rejections), you may not resolve the promise outside of the await expect statement.
Wrong
const guardMock = await guard.canActivate( // <-- error is (re-)thrown due to await
  mockExecutionContext as unknown as ExecutionContext,
);

expect(guardMock).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException)

Right
const guardMock = guard.canActivate( // <-- guardMock is now an unresolved Promise
  mockExecutionContext as unknown as ExecutionContext,
);

// guardMock will now be resolved and handled within the testing framework.
await expect(guardMock).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException)

Sync
Same goes for sync methods. When testing for sync throws (exceptions), you may not call the to be tested method directly but wrap it in a lambda that gets called by the test runner and can be caught internally.
Wrong
// This will be directly evaluated and rethrow.
expect(methodThatThrows()).toThrow(UnauthorizedException)

Right
// By passing a method to `expect`, the test runner can wrap it in a
// try ... catch block and check for an exception internally.
expect(() => methodThatThrows()).toThrow(UnauthorizedException)

